# Jquery SlideUp first times troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery you see in head is supposed to slide up the div it refers to, so do you know why it doesn't happen? Please explain me as I'm quite new to jQuery.

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".About").click(function(){
                $(".About").slideUp("slow");
            });
        });
        
        
        Documento senza titolo

```
    <body>

        <div id="main">

            <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
            <img src="LogoU.png" width="130px" height="130px" />
            </a>
            </div><!--ends logo-->

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div id="abovenavigation">

            <ul id="container">

                <li><a href="index.html"><h1 class="Home">HOME</h1></a></li><!--
                --><li><h1 class="About">ABOUT</h1></li><!--
                --><li><h1 class="Blog">BLOG</h1></li><!--
                -->

            </ul><!--ends container--> 

            </div><!--ends upper navigation-->

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div id="me">
            <img src="Gregory1.png" width**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if I understand correctly. Run this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".About").click(function(){ $(".About").slideUp("slow"); }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

            <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
            <img src="LogoU.png" width="130px" height="130px" />
            </a>
            </div><!--ends logo-->

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div id="abovenavigation">

            <ul id="container">

                <li><a href="index.html"><h1 class="Home">HOME</h1></a></li><!--
                --><li><h1 class="About">ABOUT</h1></li><!--
                --><li><h1 class="Blog">BLOG</h1></li><!--
                -->

            </ul><!--ends container--> 

            </div><!--ends upper navigation-->

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div id="me">
            <img src="Gregory1.png" /> 
              </div>
```

Comment: Yes it works! So my mistake was that I didn't add that link you put? Which means that jQuery needs to be inserted with a link, let's say, like bootsrap?